# include jquery in js file

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, google-chrome, include

I am developing chrome extension, it is a simple extension which call background.js file to do simple job. In background.js i want to include jquery.js file to call ajax function. But i can't find anyway to include jquery.js in background.js. is it possiable to do that?

you know, extension call background.js and it does not call php or html file which include background.js so i can't use anything get involved in php or html

Thanks in advance....

Comment: Just get the jquery conent, and add the text inside background.js

Comment: i thinks it is the last option, is there another solution?

Comment: Why is it the last option? This gives a lot better performance than creating a new node.

Comment: i know, but when do that, it make code become kind of static. I think there is a another solution to include

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here ya go:

```
var jQueryElement=document.createElement('script');
jQueryElement.type = 'text/javascript';
jQueryElement.src = 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js';
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(jQueryElement);
```

You will have to put everything in the onload event handler, otherwise, the rest of the JavaScript will continue running even if jQuery hasn't loaded yet.

```
var jQueryElement=document.createElement('script');
jQueryElement.type = 'text/javascript';
jQueryElement.onload = function () {
    alert('jQuery loaded');
};
jQueryElement.src = 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js';
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(jQueryElement);
```

Comment: as i mention above, we don't have php or html file

Comment: how can we do that, if we can't find head tag, because background.js run in background

Comment: There is no other way to include another JavaScript file then. This is *the* way to do it. You'll have to copy and paste jQuery into your source file.

Answer (score 4):

It sounds like you're using manifest_version 2, which means you can just add `path-to-jquery.js` to the background.scripts array.

```
"background": {
    "scripts": ["jquery.js", "background.js"]
}
```

Those files all get loaded in an generated page together, so they access the same global scope—which means you can use `jQuery` as usual.